# Filtering missing corresponding values in 1 to N relationship in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, one-to-many

I have two tables set up in a 1 to N relationship with the field `"UE"`. Table 1 is a parent. *'Table 2'* is a child.

I want to filter all entities in table2 that don't have a corresponding entity in *'Table 1'*.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Using Expression Selection and the following expression:

```
aggregate (
    layer:= 'table1',
    aggregate:= 'count',
    expression:= $id,
    filter:= "UE" = attribute (@parent,'UE'))> 0
```

the selection must be made starting from the child layer and select all the records that have a parent, then invert the selection to find the orphaned records.

OR

to select orphaned records directly, use `NOT` in front of the above expression:

```
NOT aggregate (
    layer:= 'table1',
    aggregate:= 'count',
    expression:= $id,
    filter:= "UE" = attribute (@parent,'UE'))> 0
```